# Refiling a subtree with footnotes

Tags: org-mode

I found that refiling a subtree to another file does not move
footnotes.  Does that have to be done manually, or is there a feature
that has to be turned on?

Comment: I was wondering about this as well. I do it manually. I suspect more advanced users would develop their own solutions for this.

Comment: Check out this thread over [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2016-09/msg00448.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885244/emacs-org-mode-how-can-i-refile-a-subtree-to-a-new-file
Possible duplicate of this question.

Comment: @Sati, if I remember correctly it may be possible
(automatically) to move the footnotes into the tree first, then
move it, and then move them out again.

Comment: If we know how to toggle between inline and footnote-section footnotes, then this should be easy.

Comment: This [article](https://www.wisdomandwonder.com/link/8750/only-use-in-line-footnotes-unless-your-document-is-very-very-small) seems to suggest a different approach.

Comment: @lawlist offered a solution to hide inline footnotes over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21594242/6210219).